# Escape HTML in JSON with PlayFramework2

Tags: java, backbone.js, playframework, escaping, playframework-2.0

I am using *PlayFramework2* and I can't find a way to properly handle HTML escaping.

In the template system, HTML entities are filtered by default.
But when I use REST requests with *Backbone.js*, my JSON objects are not filtered.

I use `play.libs.Json.toJson(myModel)` to transform an *Object* into a *String*.
So, in my controller, I use `return ok(Json.toJson(myModel));` to send the response ... but here, the attributes of my model are not secured.
I can't find a way to handle it ...

**Second question :**
The template engine filters HTML entities by default, this means that we have to store into our database the raw user inputs.
Is it a save behaviour ?

**Third questdion :**
Is there in the PlayFramework a function to manualy escape strings ? All those I can find require to add new dependencies.

Thanks !

**Edit :** I found a way at the *Backbone.js* templating level :
- Use `myBackboneModel.escape('attr');` instead of `myBackboneModel.get('attr');`
*Underscore.js* templating system also includes that options : `<%= attr %>` renders without escaping but `<%- attr %>` renders with escaping !
Just be careful to the efficiency, strings are re-escaped at each rendering. That's why the Backbone .create() should be prefered.

Answer (score 3):

The best practices on XSS-attacks prevention usually recommend you to reason about your **output** rather than your **input**. There's a number of reasons behind that. In my opinion the most important are:

- It doesn't make any sense to reason about escaping something unless you exactly know how you are going to output/render your data. Because different ways of rendering will require different escaping strategies, e.g. properly escaped HTML string is not good enough to use it in Javascript block. Requirements and technologies change constantly, today you render your data one way - tomorrow you might be using another (let's say you will be working on a mobile client which doesn't require HTML-escaping, because it doesn't use HTML at all to render data)  You can only be sure about proper escaping strategy while rendering your data. This is why modern frameworks delegate escaping to templating engines. I'd recommend reviewing the following article: [XSS (Cross Site Scripting) Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#A_Positive_XSS_Prevention_Model)
- Escaping user's input is actually a destructive/lossy operation – if you escape user's input before persisting it to a storage you will never find out what was his original input. There's no deterministic way to 'unescape' HTML-escaped string, consider my mobile client example above.

That is why I believe that the right way to go would be to delegate escaping to your templating engines (i.e. Play and JS-templating engine you're using for Backbone). There's no need to HTML-escape string you serialize to JSON. Notice that behind the scenes JSON-serializer will JSON-escape your strings, e.g. if you have a quote in your string it will be properly escaped to ensure resulting JSON is correct, because it's a JSON serializer after all that's why it only cares about proper JSON rendering, it knows nothing about HTML (and it shouldn't). However when you rendering your JSON data in the client side you should properly HTML-escape it using the functionality provided by the JS-templating engine you're using for Backbone.

Answering another question: you can use `play.api.templates.HtmlFormat` to escape raw HTML-string manually:

```
import play.api.templates.HtmlFormat
...
HtmlFormat.escape("<b>hello</b>").toString()
// -> &lt;b&gt;hello&lt;/b&gt;
```

If you really need to make JSON-encoder escape certain HTML strings, a good idea might be to create a wrapper for them, let's say `RawString` and provide custom `Format[RawString]` which will also HTML-escape a string in its `writes` method. For details see: [play.api.libs.json API documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.0/scala/play/api/libs/json/package.html)